# Don't work retina.js

Tags: javascript, retina.js

I have problems with retina.js.

Download images https://yadi.sk/d/VEpe-Kdz35PEfr

Why not apply @2x and @3x images? Why retina.js doesn't work? I've been doing documentation. Why this is happening? How to fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
      }

      h2 {
        margin-top: 35px;
      }

      .responsive {
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .responsive img {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .wrapper {
        background: #eaeaea;
        margin: 35px auto;
        width: 1170px;
        padding: 25px 25px 45px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .img-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
        padding: 0 15px 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }

      .img-wrapper p {
        height: 75px;
        font-size: 13px;
      }

      .bg, .bg2, .bg3 {
        height: 150px;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Uncomment one of the following CSS links to test the behavior of a
         different CSS preprocessor.-->

    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/retina.scss.css"> -->
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/retina.sass.css"> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Spoof the browser into thinking it is Retina
      // comment the next line out to make sure it works without retina
      window.devicePixelRatio = 3;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>retina.js test environement</h1>

      <h2>Img Tags</h2>

      <!-- This image does not opt in. It will always be shown at 1x -->
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <h3>Img tag @1x</h3>
        <p>
          This image does not opt in. It will always be shown at 1x.
        </p>
        <img src="google-logo.png">
      </div>

      <!-- This image should be shown at 2x all retina environments,
           but shown at 1x in non-retina environments. -->
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <h3>Img tag @2x</h3>
        <p>
          This image should be shown at 2x all retina environments,
          but shown at 1x in non-retina environments.
        </p>
        <img src="google-logo.png" data-rjs="2">
      </div>

      <!-- This image should be shown at 3x in all environments 3x and up,
           shown at 2x in 2x environments, and shown at 1x in non-retina
           environments. -->
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <h3>Img tag @3x</h3>
        <p>
          This image should be shown at 3x in all environments 3x and up,
          shown at 2x in 2x environments, and shown at 1x in non-retina
          environments.
        </p>
        <img src="google-logo.png" data-rjs="3">
      </div>    

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/retina.js/2.1.0/retina.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a bug in v2.1.0, I changed the source of the script to 2.0.0 and it works as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/retina.js/2.0.0/retina.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very match! But, when I bear retina.js on my server, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why not work retina.js on the server?

Comment: are you using the `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/retina.js/2.0.0/retina.min.js` or your own copy stored on the local server?

Comment: I'm using  own copy stored on the  server

Comment: If you copied the 2.0.0 version into the same file as you had 2.1.0, make sure you clear your cache or append a random number to the file like 'retina.js?v=2'